# Multiple line draws cause 'Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual' error

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, line

I'm drawing a series of lines from a loop (omitting the unimportant stuff):

```
     for (int i = 0; i < TLS.NumEdges - 10; i++)
            {
                MSTLine.X1 = BlueArmy[TLS.EdgeList[i, 0]].Location.X;
                MSTLine.Y1 = BlueArmy[TLS.EdgeList[i, 1]].Location.Y;   
                MSTLine.X2 = BlueArmy[TLS.EdgeList[i + 1, 0]].Location.X;
                MSTLine.Y2 = BlueArmy[TLS.EdgeList[i + 1, 0]].Location.Y;
                ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).AICanvas.Children.Add(MSTLine);
            }
```

And it throws this runtime error:
System.ArgumentException: 'Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.'

I assume it doesn't like the multiple Children.Add calls. So what is the correct method for drawing a series of lines from inside a loop? For other reasons I would rather not use polyline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI elements are classes, not structs. You have to create a new instance of MSTLine for each line that you want to create.